# Uploading image via S3 pre-signed URL. When downloading image, it's not accessible. Setting Content-Type invalidates signature

Tags: amazon-s3, file-upload, content-type, pre-signed-url

I am trying to upload images to S3 directly from the browser using a pre-signed URL. I have got it working, in that the file gets uploaded where I expect it to be.

My problem is that when I download the image from S3 I cannot open it on my Mac (error is unrecognised format, or damaged file). It's just a normal jpg file.

I have a Lambda set up on AWS exposed via the API Gateway that generates the pre-signed URL for me. The Lambda is written in Go (this is my first project to get familiar with Go).

On the front-end, I am using Axios to upload the image - nothing too complex in terms of any other. It works fine, apart from the problem mentioned above. The file is uploaded with the same amount of data as it is locally (so the file is not empty).

I have tried enforcing the `Content-Type` to `image/jpeg` when generating the pre-signed URL, but this stops me being able to upload at all as it says

> `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

From what I can see in the error returned (see below), the content type it is receiving is `multipart/form-data`, but I am not sure how content types work with multipart form submissions.

This is the Go code in the Lambda that generates the pre-signed URL (including content type):

```golang
// filename - <uuid>.jpg
// filetype - "image/jpeg"
req, _ := svc.PutObjectRequest(&s3.PutObjectInput{
  Bucket:      aws.String("facial-api"),
  Key:         aws.String(filename),
  ContentType: aws.String(filetype),
})
```

The upload request from the browser:

```
// get file data
const file = fileInput && fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0] || null;

// create form data
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);

// put request
axios.put(this.uploadURL, formData)
.then(res => {
  console.log(res)
})
```

The error I get back:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
   <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
   <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
   <AWSAccessKeyId>ABC123</AWSAccessKeyId>
   <StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20190531T111729Z
20190531/eu-west-1/s3/aws4_request
69c2673b27fde3743fc3ce426e959bc152f49f140650e5cfce4017ee13275524</StringToSign>
   <SignatureProvided>9745749ff83b1591fc7ee08d2796d7151d5952e7c4ada738c058db347d0791f5</SignatureProvided>
   <StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d....</StringToSignBytes>
   <CanonicalRequest>PUT
/328733de-bf61-4e85-8978-851e5b6021f6.jpg
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=ASIA6E6TKZI66G23KCVJ%2F20190531%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20190531T111729Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=900&amp;X-Amz-Security-Token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEHMaCWV1LXdlc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCtRrALimM9jMPuJGgwP3xQFq2bXUxdfw0cW%2F09llPDNgIhAIBMmj2pXxlp%2Br2EkPEjUKJxaFieNtwcP9IdHEVwxnrnKp0CCIz%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQABoMOTcyNzE2NDI3ODM3Igwb5R%2FR4XFjwVhmkm4q8QGVCt%2Bocco26F3ZHuDya%2BTA%2BSa442QRixv0NBrhZH76cktkLtUE7t%2Baq6NzDUTGodXC4Ta8qvY%2BJ6RHaOzH1eGGFC9R%2FSD3uTGfqdUiipBkC2Fbw1VzdNNOvqVIX8qli0%2Bja08vDcZBCOLys%2BE7emCnNNMy8%2FZZnAXpA4V1pM9XKhjwmZqjrA%2BVAcYwpodcrUXfyEb7fZ6J%2B1IEoVsPuRgSomcQcMNiG5aTRJ5F7TCMDDU9T0%2F%2B2OObe7rDNgMTeG3WJOBDuq5GZdXj5YeZNkbGT2e6gf0UI64jpV%2FBIy685L7oOsxjWtnWP5sQ9ehDQV4KMLeUxOcFOrMBHfJ5mOrCedP35Fak9C5ufeVDYhdg%2Fyf4pqQRB4iUR8WVEwHPhGrZgWseWm4F6h7%2FJi%2F96HprpZdP1i22cH6WdV%2B6zBEWLUxrMLJrp8TbNWqCxRX0nBK8SU9CAInioFUTXtLtTtCU8VLtMWcSz8H5G2lS0RBWRulnKApPhXKjgasbDW%2FNyAbz1lYHfoK%2FwYixNxxNu5KPR8W8Tcgkd77iI6sv5kBauPg8cPNEgtRgwTMcER8%3D&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost
content-type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarytvKIVaU0MCOgbXT7
host:facial-api.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

content-type;host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest>
   <CanonicalRequestBytes>50 55 54 0a 2f 33 32 38 37 33...</CanonicalRequestBytes>
   <RequestId>601F19984870DFAC</RequestId>
<HostId>XuSYqxIKEzD7XpDliU9kIGnsW8sIQzS4okXqDIuVVwB3Az+V276x2no47eDcY4OG+xQ3mh1yQeA=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I only get this error when defining the `Content-Type` at the generation of the URL. I would expect this to upload my image, and let me download it in a format that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your header permission Content-Type.
Content-Type should be an image type

Answer (score -1):

Backend use Golang:

```
params := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(c.awsS3Config.BucketName),
        Key:    aws.String(fileName),
    }
req, _ := c.s3ForPreSign.PutObjectRequest(params)
url, err := req.Presign(5 * time.Minute)
```

In Frontend, please send direct file binary in body (not use FormData):

The value of Content-Type will automatically follow MIMEType of file.
Test Postman:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e6gS.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your answer from getting deleted.